# Next Auth keeps using localhost with google provider even when redirect uri is set to the proper address

Tags: next.js, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, next-auth

Next Auth when calling `/api/auth/providers` keeps returning localhost even though on google cloud platform the oauth key is set to use the proper production uri.

Response from `/api/auth/providers`:

```json
{
  "google": {
    "id": "google",
    "name": "Google",
    "type": "oauth",
    "signinUrl": "http://localhost:3000/api/auth/signin/google",
    "callbackUrl": "http://localhost:3000/api/auth/callback/google"
  }
}
```

Google Cloud Platform Setup:
[Google cloud platform setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDVJv.png)

What have I done wrong?
Am I missing something?

Thank you,
Giacomo

P.S. the app is being deployed through vercel if it could be of any help

I tried redeploy by recreating the project on google workspace but nothing is working. I'm having the same problem on my local machine but I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: I've tried on my local machine and by setting```NEXTAUTH_URL``` it works when running the server with ```npm run dev``` (which uses next dev), but it does not work when using ```vercel dev```. As they both call ```next dev``` why doesn't this work?